# Enable iframe on specified host

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I do currently run a website.
On this website I have a few videos which are iframed from my video server.

I'm hosting the video's in JWplayer on the video server, which I then iframe into my own website.

Now I have found some websites which iframe my player into their site, or just re-direct them to the play on the video server.

I know I can just put the player into the page but I do not want that.

Basically my question is how do I redirect people to http://www.server1.com/video1.html (this is the site where server2.com/videoplayer.html is iframed) if the Jwplayer is not loaded with server1 as URL.

So I want people to only see the player if the main url is server1.com

I can change the player to the second site if needed, I just want to iframe the player without others being to iframe it or watch the player trough the iframe URL.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this.  If you are using apache for your video server you can use a mod rewrite statement to check the referring host and only allow specific hosts to see the video.

You can do the same by encapsulating your video page in an php, python, perl, ruby script again checking the referring host to reject them if they are not in your white list.

Answer (score 0):

You could check in the browser and set a header of ALLOW-FROM uri

For Firefox and IE
X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM uri

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

For other browsers you could check the parent url
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/04/16/getting-the-url-of-an-iframes-parent/

```
function checkWhiteList() {
  // if is in iframe
  if (parent !== window) {
       var parentUrl = document.referrer;
       if(!inWhiteList(parentUrl)) {
          redirectToErrorPage();
       }
   }
}
```